# What quick Thanksgiving treats can I make?

Tags: cookies, popcorn, thanksgiving

I don't have much cooking experience, and I want to contribute to our Thanksgiving dinner. I've just popped some popcorn but don't know what to do now.

Anyways, I need some simple 5-30 minute snacks I can make to add something to our Thanksgiving dinner. I'm open to suggestions! We have an oven, microwave, griddle, popcorn popper, lots of pots and pans, big sink, so I'm probably good in that regard.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I see you managed to get an answer already, but in general, we don't do "what should I make?" questions - there are just too many possibilities. If you have more questions like this, you can ask them in [chat], though you'll have to make a real post or two and get a couple upvotes for the site to let you in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about applesauce muffins? They require minimal effort, taste amazing, and take about half an hour to make (which includes waiting time where you can make other things).

Comment: I have three tupperware containers full of applesauce! Hmm...let's see..

Comment: Glad to have helped! There are plenty of great and simple apple recipes out there! Frosting is also easy to make, and there are countless simple ways to decorate if you want to add a little something. Those are a matter of personal preference though, as oppose to a necessity!